# How to create new component/directive in jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

How do you properly add new directives/components in a jhipster project? I see that you can run commands to generate entities and services, but no directives.... what is the proper way to do this?

```
yo jhipster:service bar
yo jhipster:entity <entityName>
```

I don't see anything for yo jhipster:directive or yo jhipster:component.
How do I create a directive/component?

Comment: I dont fully understand the question. You mean so that the generator picks up your directive, Or whats the convention?

Comment: Modified original post to show you what I am confused about.

Comment: I am not sure what the process to create a new directive? Am I just creating new files that match the convention? Or is there some "yo jhipster:directive newalert" command i can run to generate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no sub generator for directive or component assuming you're talking about JHipster 3 and angular 1.x. The entity sub generator generates both server and client code, there's no sub generator for client code only.

With JHipster 4 and angular 2, you will be able to use angular-cli for this kind of small operations on client code.

Comment: this week we should have a beta version

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide more specifics, with **JHipster 4 and angular 2** you can use the regular angular-cli as follows to create a directive:

1. Open a terminal and change directory to where you want to create the directive e.g.

`cd /App/src/main/webapp/app/home`

2. To create the directive type:

`ng g directive <NAME-OF-YOUR-DIRECTIVE>`

This will create two files: *.directive.ts and *.directive.spec.ts

It may also modify the module file (or you may have to modify it manually e.g. you may have to modify home.module.ts to add references to the newly created directive).